# pumaとnginxにてlet's encryptを使用したSSL化に失敗する。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

・Rails(puma)
・nginx
・let's encrypt

という構成で、https化させようとしております (httpでの動作確認はできております)。

let's encryptでの証明書発行も完了しており、nginxに記載をしております。
httpsのポートも開いており、rails側では`config/environments/production.rb`にある
`force_ssl`も`true`にしております。

ただ、httpsでアクセスしても「このサイトにアクセスできません」と表示されます。
どこかの設定に不備があるのですが、その原因の切り分けに困っております。

宜しくお願い致します。

#### 起動方法は、以下のコマンドを実行

```
$ puma -C config/puma.rb -e production
```

#### 設定情報

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/sample_app.conf
```

※ /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample_app/fullchain.pem などのファイルは実際に存在していることを確認しております。sample_appの部分は実際のサービスのドメイン名になっております。

```
upstream my_app {
  server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
}
log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
                '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
                '$http_x_forwarded_for';

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sample_app; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier
  return      301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_protocols SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_ciphers 'kEECDH+ECDSA+AES128 kEECDH+ECDSA+AES256 kEECDH+AES128 kEECDH+AES256 kEDH+AES128 kEDH+AES256 DES-CBC3-SHA +SHA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !kECDH !DSS !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !CAMELLIA !SEED';
  ssl_stapling on;
  ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;


  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample_app/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sample_app/privkey.pem;
  server_name sample_app; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier
  # server_name _ localhost; # need to listen to localhost for worker tier

  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
    set $year $1;
    set $month $2;
    set $day $3;
    set $hour $4;
  }

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /assets {
    alias </path/to/app>/public/assets;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location /public {
    alias </path/to/app>/public;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
}
```

config/puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
plugin :tmp_restart
bind "unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock"
```

#### ポート確認

httpsポートは空いていて、nginxで使用できているようにみえますが、違ってますでしょうか？

$ ss -tulp state listening

```
Netid  Recv-Q Send-Q                                           Local 
Address:Port                                                            
Peer Address:Port
tcp    0      100                                                  
127.0.0.1:smtp                                                                       
*:*                     users:(("master",pid=1067,fd=13))
tcp    0      128                                                          
*:https                                                                      
*:*                     users:(("nginx",pid=31011,fd=7), 
("nginx",pid=31010,fd=7))
tcp    0      128                                                          
*:http                                                                       
*:*
```

Comment: より広く回答を募るため、こちらにも質問させていただいております。https://teratail.com/questions/151281

Comment: 「このサイトにアクセスできません」と表示される際、他にエラーコードや、メッセージが表示されてませんか？もしアレば、トラブルシュートのヒントになるので、質問を編集して追記をお願いします。 直感では、Nginxで他のバーチャルホストが設定されていて、そちらに接続されてるんじゃ？という予感がしてます。可能なら Nginxの設定を 全部書いてみてください。Includeしている他のファイルが存在する可能性もありますので併せてご確認ください。